# git remote - how to change references

Tags: git, github

How do I change this? When I do a  `git show-ref`, I see the following:

```
    963958ed832e82759362f87599bc9799bcfa46d9 refs/heads/origin
    8c4e0f4c3aa147582d92302c73bf5bb81c335f60 refs/remotes/origin/main
```

It needs to say `git show-ref`

```
    985b5395c54e89fc3b825464f9d41c2cf9f1bf36 refs/heads/heroku
    985b5395c54e89fc3b825464f9d41c2cf9f1bf36 refs/heads/master
    985b5395c54e89fc3b825464f9d41c2cf9f1bf36 refs/remotes/heroku/master
    985b5395c54e89fc3b825464f9d41c2cf9f1bf36 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Why and how would it say that? What is the point of trying to imagine what show-ref _should_ say, and why should it say that in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to show refs from a remote named heroku, you should:

- make sure you do have such a remote.
  If not: `git remote add heroku /heroku/url`
- fetch from heroku, in order to have something locally that git show-ref can display:
  `git fetch heroku`